# ng-repeat on ng-include to include same page multiple times

Tags: angularjs

I have a ng-include inside of the ng-repeat. All the ng-include is including the same html page. When I update the html page in one of the ng-repeat cycle, it updates all the ng-includes. I am wondering if I could ng-include the same page, but allow to change one without changing another

workout html

```
<div ng-repeat="workout in workoutList">
  {{workout["name"]}} - {{workout["description"]}}
 <button ng-click="showDiv = !showDiv; show(workout.id)"> + </button>
 <div ng-show="showDiv" ng-include="'workout/_show.html'"></div>
</div>
```

show html

```
{{workoutShowList}}
<button>Add new Exercise</button>
```

show controller

```
    $scope.show = function(workout_id){
        WorkoutService.show($scope.id, workout_id).then(function(response){
            $scope.workoutShowList = response.data
        })
    }
```

Comment: Never include the parent inside itself. Declare a script template and include it inside the first call

Comment: what do you mean by "When I update the html page in one of the ng-repeat cycle" ?

Comment: When I click on the first `+` sign, it will show all its item a, b, c, d, and e. When I click on the second '+' sign, it will show all its item a2, b2, c2, d2, etc. But when you click second + sign, the first sets of item are also changed. The work around is to assign each of them a copy of your controller. Which works ok, but if your controller has something to be run automatically, then every one of this repeat will call this controller once which is super inefficient.